# Zoom to selected feature, without using 'current' in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python, geoprocessing, select

I am wondering if it is possible to build a zoom to geoprocessing service without using 'current' for the MXD variable in Python?  Using 'current' my tool works in ArcMap, but not in my geoprocessing service.

Here is my code that work fine locally in ArcMap:

```
import arcpy


MXD=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')    
dataframe = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD, "Web Mercator")[0]   
dataframe.zoomToSelectedFeatures() 
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

When I publish my service, the zoom feature no longer works.  I have read online that you can't use 'current' in a geoprocessing service, that's fine.  When I enter the path to the MXD, the zoom function no longer works.

Comment: Is there a way to use a variable as 'current' with the mxd path in it?

Comment: I don't know much about GP services, but since it is server side, not client side, doesn't that mean it is unable to affect/interact with the current map document/active view?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set the path to your map - CURRENT only works if you're in ArcMap.

```
MXD=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\data\new.mxd')
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code supplied in the question it is not possible to see how you can tell that the zoom is not working when you specify the mxd (which is the way I do this) rather than `CURRENT`.

Perhaps include an `MXD.save()`, `MXD.SaveACopy(...)`, or an `arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(...)` to "trap" the result.